# Adding Multiple Dictionaries to iOS plist for Journal

Tags: ios, objective-c, dictionary, nsdictionary, plist

I have an app in which I want to store several pieces of information throughout the life of the app.  To do this, I have made a plist file called 'myJournal.plist'.  There won't be anything in the plist at first, as it will be completely dependent on what the user does.  I would like the plist to look something like this, where each Dictionary is based on the current day and added to the list.

[image]

I have the following in my code:

```
NSArray *directories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documents = [directories firstObject];
    NSString *filename = [documents stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myJournal.plist"];
    NSMutableDictionary *loadedMiscDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:filename];
    NSMutableDictionary *tempDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    [tempDict setValue:distractions.text forKey:@"distractions"];
    [tempDict setValue:revelations.text forKey:@"revelations"];

    [loadedMiscDictionary addEntriesFromDictionary:tempDict];
    [loadedMiscDictionary writeToFile:filename atomically:YES];
```

But nothing gets changed.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First time you may be trying to write into file which is either not created yet or empty thus your `loadedMiscDictionary` is `nil`. As a result, at the end you're trying to write `nil` into file.
2. The file in the bundle (which is on the screenshot, I assume) is not the same file that resides in Documents directory. Enable documents sharing and check your app's Documents directory in iTunes. I think you'll see the file that is actually altered there.